# Unable to click on 'more' button cyclically to get all the full reviews

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script in python in combination with selenium to fetch all the reviews from a certain page of google maps. There are lots of reviews in that page and they are only visible once that page is made to scroll downward. My script can do all of them successfully.

However, the only issue that I'm facing at this moment is that some of the reviews have `More` button which is meant to click in order to show the full review.

One of such is this:

[image]

[website address](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pizzeria+Di+Matteo/@40.8512552,14.255779,17z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf!8m2!3d40.8512512!4d14.2579677!9m1!1b1)

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pizzeria+Di+Matteo/@40.8512552,14.255779,17z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x133b0841ef6e38e5:0xece6ea09987e9baf!8m2!3d40.8512512!4d14.2579677!9m1!1b1"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

while True:
    try:
        elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-loading-spinner']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",elem)
    except Exception:
        break

    for see_more in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class^='section-expand-review']"))):
        see_more.click()


for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-review-content"))):
    name = item.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='section-review-title'] > span").text
    try:
        review = item.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='section-review-text']").text
    except AttributeError:
        review = ""
    print(name)

driver.quit()
```

Currently the above script throws `stale element` error when it hits this line `for see_more in wait.until().click()`.

***How can I click on that `More` button cyclically to get all the full reviews?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `WebdriverWait` and `presence_of_all_elements_located` it wait for search the element in given time and if it is not attached to the html you will receive error.

However Check the length of element present in webpage if there then click on the element.

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class^='section-expand-review']"))>0:
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class^='section-expand-review']").click()
```

Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ecstasy/@23.7399982,90.3732109,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m7!3m6!1s0x3755b8caa669d5e3:0x41f47ddcc39a556e!8m2!3d23.7399933!4d90.3753996!9m1!1b1"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

while True:
    try:
        elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='section-loading-spinner']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",elem)
    except Exception:
        break

    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class^='section-expand-review']"))>0:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class^='section-expand-review']").click()
        print('pass')



for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-review-content"))):
    name = item.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='section-review-title'] > span").text
    try:
        review = item.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='section-review-text']").text
    except AttributeError:
        review = ""
    print(name)

driver.quit()
```

**EDITED**

```
 if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class^='section-expand-review']"))>0:

    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class^='section-expand-review']"):
        item.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        item.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Your solution works inconsistently. I tried few times and noticed that it kept on clicking on that button but somewhere within the execution it breaks throwing the same error. Btw, as you didn't define any loop, how can that click be initiated on all the `more` buttons if there are several `more` buttons in each scroll? Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU : I have tried the same code few times which I posted and working fine.I don't know why you are getting error

Comment: second thing you can loop there as well.check edited option.

Comment: The reason you didn't encounter any error is because the url I used in the first place within my post contained very few reviews. I've edited my post to put there the original url from where the above image has been taken. Thanks.

Comment: Its a bit tricky.However I can you give it a try and let me know how it goes.check the edited section

Answer (score 0):

this is worked with me :-
you can put it within for loop or your method to get all reviews.

```
try:                
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("mapsConsumerUiSubviewSectionReview__section-expand-review").click()
except:
   continue
```